# Showing custom post code in post excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am building a website which will be used for posting tables in each post. For this purpose I have written a custom post code which enables the user to create tables simply by using ACF and data from database.

The thing is I would like to show the table also in the excerpt of the each post but I only get the post text written in the WP Post, written by the end user.

For now i have set it this way:

```
    <!-- Blog Content -->

    <?php echo $current_post['content']; 

    //Start my custom table code (HTML + PHP)?>
    <table style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .         
    </table>                

    <?php
    //End my custom table code
    ?>
```

Right now, only the content which is written by the end user ($current_post['content']) is showing in the excerpt, while in full post preview my custom table is showed normally.

What is the best way to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$head1Title = $_POST['postTitle'];
$text = $_POST['postText'];
<table> 
<tr> <th><?php echo $head1Title; ?> </th> </tr>
<tr> <td> <?php echo $text; ?></td></tr>

</table>
```

maybe try this one example?